# Show there are $b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)= {a\over 2}x^2 + bx + c$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

> Given $f:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f''(x) = a.\forall x\in I$.
>   Show there are $b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)= {a\over 2}x^2  + bx + c$.

If we define $g(x) = ax + b$, then $g'(x) = f''(x) = a$. Therefore, $f'(x)$ and $g(x)$ are equal (maybe differ by a constant). Hence, $f'(x)$ has to have the form: $f'(x) = ax + b$

I've been told to use Lagrange's Mean Value Thm but I'm not sure why the above alone isn't sufficient.

P.S
I wrote "Therefore, $f'(x)$ and $g(x)$ are equal (maybe differ by a constant)". How should I write it in a more professional/mathematical way?

Comment: You can just integrate $f''(a)$..

Comment: Can you expand your answer @Krokop, and what should I do instead?

Comment: If you are not familiar with integration you cannot use this method. Look at $f(x)$ in your answer, what can you say about $f'(x)$ ? and $f''(x)$ ? (You have to justify that $f$ is twice differentiable)

Comment: It is given that $f''(x) = a$ therefore, $f(x)$ is at least twice differentiable, isn't it?

Comment: yes, but with integration we have $f(x)$ in your answer and reciprocally if $f(x)=\frac{a}{2}x^2+bx+c$ then $f''(x)=a$. But if you are unfamiliar with integration I do not see how you can do your exercise..And did you know when your function admit a primitive ?

Comment: Well, I've been told to use Lagrange's MVT. What do you mean "function admit a primitive"?

Comment: oh my bad i did not see that, can you expand what did you mean bu Lagrange's MVT ?

Comment: Sure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

Comment: Thanks, it's just the MTV : I am not sure you can do this with the MVT but perhaps I am wrong..

Answer (score 1):

I  would just say that given $f''(x) = a$, and integrating with respect to $x$ twice will give you the desired result. 
 $\int f''(x) dx= \int a dx = ax + b$, where $b$ is a constant. Then,
 $\int f'(x) dx= \int ax + b dx = {(ax^2)\over2} + bx + c$, where $c$ is a constant. 
 and this is the form you wanted.

Comment: Thank you, but it's a calculus I course and therefore, we are not familiar with integration.

Comment: Could you help me figure out how to use Lagrange's MVT?

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer: 
For $f'(x)$: Consider any two $x_1$ and $x_2$, by LMVT, $\frac{f'(x_1)-f'(x_2)}{x_1-x_2} = a $, which is the equation for a straight line, with slope $a$, and so $f'(x) = ax + b$. I am not sure if the next extension is as simple. I'll try to complete the rest and edit this reply.
[Edit]:
At $x_3$ and $x_4$, for $f(x)$, by LMVT:  $\frac{f(x_3)-f(x_4)}{x_3-x_4} = a\frac{x_3+x_4}{2}+b $, let $x_4 = 0$ and $x_3=x$. Then, $\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} = a\frac{x}{2}+b$ which gives, $f(x) = \frac{ax^2}{2}+bx + c$ where, $c=f(0)$
I think even for $f'(x)$ computation, setting $x_2=0$ and $x_1=x$ would be better, than directly using straight line equation.

$$
\frac{f'(x_1)-f'(x_2)}{x_1-x_2} = a, with x_1=x, x_2=0
$$ 
becomes
$$
\frac{f'(x)-f'(0)}{x} = a \implies f'(x) = ax+b, b=f'(0)
$$

PS: Thanks a lot for an interesting approach, that most of us wouldn't have thought of.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't understand how can you determine that $\frac{f(x_3)-f(x_4)}{x_3-x_4} = a\frac{x_3+x_4}{2}+b$. All you know by LMVT is that $x_3 < c < x_4$ so it isn't necessarily ${x_3 + x_4} \over 2$

Comment: You are right. During the edit, I got carried away - which also prompted me to add the "PS: part, as I was surprised at this "new look at integration". While $f'(x) = ax + b$ is valid, the second part is not. Or at least I am not able to reconstruct my thought process (which I doubt). You have to "un"accept this answer, if possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, we're halfway there ;)